# Preference settings - how to disable change listener while enable click listener?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm building a settings screen. Some features should be locked for the free user, and when he click on that preference, a toast message tells him that this is a PRO only feature.

If I try `preference.setEbabled(false)` then try to implement an onClick listener, nothing happens and the item remains just disabled.

I don't want to add a null change listener, as in ListPreference it will show the selection dialog, which I don't want.

How to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with `.setActivated(false)` instead of `.setEnabled(false)`. In your OnClick you can check if activated or not with `.isActivated()` and proceed based on the return value.

Comment: `setActivated` is not an option in settings type activity items

Comment: Ah I see, I was thinking about buttons/views. Sorry about that. I'm short on time at the moment, but I found a couple of answers that might help you: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566303/make-preference-look-disabled-but-still-register-clicks) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490502/how-to-allow-clicking-on-disabled-preferences-or-mimic-disabled-preferences-fun)

Comment: That inspired me a lot! Many thanks, problem fixed :)